# How to Handle or Architecture, incremental data ingestion in Azure data lake Store?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-lake

I've Two Custom code dll, for Image related to IP Cams.

**dll-One** : Extract image from IP cams and can be stored it to Azure data lake Store.

**Like** :

- /adls/clinic1/patientimages
- /adls/clinic2/patientimages

**dll-two** : Use those image and extract information from it and load data into RDBMS tables.

So for instance in RDBMS ,say there are entities dimpatient, dimclinic and factpatientVisit.

For start, a one time data can be exported to defined location in Azure data lake store.

**Like:**

- /adls/dimpatient
- /adls/dimclinic
- /adls/factpatientVisit

**Question :**
How to push incremental data in same file or how we can handle this incremental load in Azure data Analytics?

This like implementing Warehouse in Azure Data Analytics.

**Note**: Azure SQL db or any other storage offered by Azure is not want to.
I mean why to spend in other Azure Services if one type of storage has capabilities to hold all types of data.

**adls** is name of my ADLS storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure I completely understand your question, but you can organize your data files in Azure Data Lake Store or your rows in partitioned U-SQL tables along a time dimension, so you can add new partitions/files for each increment. In general, we recommend that such increments are of substantial sizes though to preserve the ability to scale.

Comment: I'm targeting to implement datawarehouse in ADLS, but as ADLS is file type store. How can we implement incremental load in such scenario.

Comment: What I understood from your opinion is  to create each year and then month and date folder and then my dimension and fact for that day will resides as file. So if my storage name is ADLS I should create or partition my data like  ADLS/2017/04/19/ beneath which there can be three files for each entity and can continue same concept for next day. Enlightened me if I understood correctly your suggestion.

Comment: Also reason for focusing on warehouse type architecture because I want it to do profiling on base of patient and clinic using Azure ML , like we use historical data for data mining and finding pattern out of it.

Comment: If you want to use files, you understood me correctly. Alternatively, you could use partitioned U-SQL tables and use a partition per day for example. See http://aka.ms/usql_reference (specifically `CREATE TABLE` and `ALTER TABLE`)  for details on how to create and manage partitioned tables.

Comment: Thanks for link, it precisely gave me a light for my vision of implementation with old school skills.